# Como interactuar con inputs type file?

Tags: php, html

Cuando tengo un formulario con un input de tipo `file` al enviarlo, en mi acción receptora como puedo comprobar si está set o no ya que con

```
if (isset($_POST['my_file'])){ echo "bla"; }
```

no funciona

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my_form" action="<?php echo $yomismo; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="my_file">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la variable global `$_POST` a `$_FILES`.

Luego para comprobar si el archivo se ha subido exitosamente lo puedes comprobar de esta forma:

```
$phpFileUploadErrors = [
    0 => 'No hay error, el archivo se ha subido con éxito',
    1 => 'El archivo subido supera la directiva upload_max_filesize en php.ini',
    2 => 'El archivo subido supera la directiva MAX_FILE_SIZE que se especificó en el formulario HTML',
    3 => 'El archivo subido sólo se cargó parcialmente',
    4 => 'No se ha cargado ningún archivo',
    6 => 'Falta una carpeta temporal',
    7 => 'Error al escribir el archivo en el disco',
    8 => 'Una extensión de PHP detuvo la subida del archivo',
];

if ($_FILES['my_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    // El archivo se ha cargado con éxito

}
else {

    // Hubo un error
    echo $phpFileUploadErrors[$_FILES['my_file']['error']];
}
```

[+ Info sobre los posibles errores](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: Al final lo que he hecho ha sido comprobar que el `$_FILES['imagen_nombre']['error'] != 4`

Comment: @PavloB. - Deberías comprobar que no sea ninguno de los fallos... es decir: `== 0` o `==UPLOAD_ERR_OK`

Answer (score 2):

Se verifica de esta forma:

```
 if( isset($_FILES['my_file']) && count($_FILES['my_file']['error']) == 1 && $_FILES['my_file']['error'][0] > 0)
{
     //file no seleccionado
}
else if(isset($_FILES['my_file']))
{
     echo "blah seleccionado";
}
```

Ve ejemplos más extendidos [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928409/4987172).

Comment: Pero si hago eso, aunque no ponga nada en el input me entra dentro del if...

Comment: @PavloB. he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: @PavloB. Los ficheros van con $_FILES, no con $_POST. Tienes que tener cuidado con eso.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba controlar si el tamaño del archivo es mayor a 0, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
...
if ($_FILES['my_file']['size'] > 0) { 
   echo "bla";
}
...
```